# Matlab: convert int array into string array?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, integer

In Matlab I have integer array a=[1 2 3]. I need to convert them into one string, separated by ',':

```
c = '1,2,3'
```

If somehow I can have a string array b=['1' '2' '3'], then I can use

```
c = strjoin(b, ',')
```

to achieve the goal.

So my question is: How to convert integer array a=[1 2 3] into a string array b=['1' '2' '3']?

The int2str() is not working. It will give out

```
'1 2 3'
```

and it is not a "string array", so the strjoin can not apply to it to achieve '1,2,3'

Comment: Thanks for the 3 answers that can  get the c = '1,2,3' . But my own answer below is the only one that actually "convert int array into string array" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `sprintf()`:

```
a = 1:3;
c = sprintf('%d,',a);
c = c(1:end-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a [function in the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22937-convert-a-vectorarraymatrix-of-values-into-a-comma-separated-string) called `vec2str` that'll do this.

You'll need to set the `encloseFlag` parameter to `0` to remove the square brackets. Example:

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = vec2str(a,[],[],0);
```

Inside `b` you'll have:

```
b = 
    '1,2,3'
```

Comment: sounds good, but not as simple as Oleg's solution, especially when it requires downloading a file :)

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution myself:

after getting the string (not array), split it:

```
b = int2str();   %b='1  2  3'
c = strsplit(b); %c='1' '2' '3'
```

Then I can get the result c=strjoin(c, ',') as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
c = regexprep(num2str(a), '\s*', ',');
```